# Is a PATCH that leads to a DELETE of a resource appropriate for a REST API?

Tags: api, rest

Consider the idea that I have a resource called Posts (the equivalent table in my database is named `Post`) and it has a subresource[?] (field/attribute for Post table) called `numberOfDislikes`.

Periodically, `PATCH /api/v1/posts/123` is requested in order to increment the `numberOfDislikes` field.

Within the callback function that runs when a `PATCH /api/v1/posts/123` request is made, when the `numberOfDislikes` reaches `10`, the posts with ID = 123 is deleted.

**Is that RESTful?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**. The client sends the `PATCH` to alter the server state of the resource. If this is successfull, the server returns a response to the client which tells the client that the `PATCH` was successfull.

If now, based entirely on logic on the server side, the server state of the resource leads to it be it deleted, this has nothing to do with the RESTfulness of the server. It is just server logic.

If the client now `GET`s the resource the server should respond with the proper HTTP response [`410 Gone`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error):

> Indicates that the resource requested is no longer available and will not be available again. This should be used when a resource has been intentionally removed and the resource should be purged.

That is exactly what happend: the resource is no longer available.